# How compareAndSet works internally in redis

Tags: java, spring, redis

`spring-data-redis` module contains `RedisAtomicLong` class.

In this class you can see

```
public boolean compareAndSet(long expect, long update) {

    return generalOps.execute(new SessionCallback<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Boolean execute(RedisOperations operations) {
            for (;;) {
                operations.watch(Collections.singleton(key));
                if (expect == get()) {
                    generalOps.multi();
                    set(update);
                    if (operations.exec() != null) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My question is why it works?

`generalOps.multi()` starts transaction after `get()` is invoked. It means that there is possibility that two different thread (or even client) can change value and both of them will succeed.

Is `operations.watch` prevent it somehow? JavaDoc doesn't explain purpose of this method.

PS: Minor question: why `for (;;)`? There is always one iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q: Is operations.watch prevent it somehow?**

**YES.**

Quoting from [Redis documentation about transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#optimistic-locking-using-check-and-set):

> WATCH is used to provide a check-and-set (CAS) behavior to Redis transactions.
>
> WATCHed keys are monitored in order to detect changes against them. If at least one watched key is modified before the EXEC command, the whole transaction aborts, and EXEC returns a Null reply to notify that the transaction failed.

You can learn more about Redis transaction from that documentation.

**Q: why for (;;)? There is always one iteration.**

It seems the code you've posted is very old. From Google's cache of [this url](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/121864-problem-with-compareandset-in-redis), I saw the code you provided which is dated back to `Oct 15th, 2012`!

Latest codes look much different:

- [compareAndSet method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/3a07a0d8ed5ba6c3ad399190d0f9df5f5e19cc97/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/support/atomic/RedisAtomicLong.java#L198-L200)
- [CompareAndSet class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/3a07a0d8ed5ba6c3ad399190d0f9df5f5e19cc97/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/support/atomic/CompareAndSet.java)

Answer (score 2):

> Is operations.watch prevent it somehow?

YES. After watching a key, if the key has been modified before transaction finishes, `EXEC` will fail. So if `EXEC` successes, the value is guaranteed to be unchanged by others.

> why for (;;)? There is always one iteration.

In your case, it seems the infinite loop is redundant.

However, if you want to implement a check-and-set operation to modify the value with the old value, the infinite loop is necessary. Check this example from [redis doc](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#optimistic-locking-using-check-and-set):

```
WATCH mykey
val = GET mykey
val = val + 1
MULTI
SET mykey $val
EXEC
```

Since `EXEC` might fail, you need to retry the whole process in a loop until it successes.

Answer (score 1):

`RedisAtomicLong.compareAndSet` implementation is not optimal since it requires **5 requests to Redis**

[Redisson](https://github.com/redisson/redisson) - Redis Java client provides more efficient implementation.

`org.redisson.RedissonAtomicLong#compareAndSetAsync` method implemented using atomic EVAL-script:

```
  "local currValue = redis.call('get', KEYS[1]); "
+ "if currValue == ARGV[1] "
       + "or (tonumber(ARGV[1]) == 0 and currValue == false) then "
      + "redis.call('set', KEYS[1], ARGV[2]); "
      + "return 1 "
+ "else "
      + "return 0 "
+ "end",
```

This script requires only **single request to Redis**.

Usage example:

```
RAtomicLong atomicLong = redisson.getAtomicLong("myAtomicLong");
atomicLong.compareAndSet(1L, 2L);
```